# MYSQL multiple select query in one php page

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying for days now to catogorize my videos on a browsepage, but when i try. One sql gives results and the other one says it has 0 results.

```
    <?php
include("db-conct.php");

$cato = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE `cato` = 'cato' ORDER BY views DESC";
$result = $conn->query($cato);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    }
}else{
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
<?php
$cato1 = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE `cato` = 'cato' ORDER BY views DESC";
$result = $conn->query($cato1);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    }
}else{
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I hope someone knows what the problem is.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @Funk I'm so sorry i forgot about it. I had to wait for 10 minutes so i start coding again. I've added the solved answer and i try to remember for the next time not to edit my question. Seems logic :) Thanks

Comment: @Riggs Thank you, that's very nice :) I'm going to use it!

Comment: you're welcome @ConstantBrummer *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're closing your connection after the first query:

```
$conn->close();
```

You should add error handling to your queries.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: You're right man. It worked. Such a simple thing that i didnt saw. I use error handling but i tought maybe i waste ur time. Thank you so much

Comment: The error should say something more useful than your 0 results, like the connection was closed.

Comment: This is a really good one ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);